# Is there any CI for free pascal?

Tags: continuous-integration, freepascal

I want to do some Free Pascal projects. Before that, does anyone know how to do CI (continue integration) for FPC?

Comment: CI tools usually are not programming language dependent

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, most tools will work. Try Jenkins.

Comment: Jenkins is OK. but I have to write many sh scripts to make it work, is there some easy way?

Comment: You just need a way to compile your program without an ide, e.g. use makefiles.

Answer (score 0):

FPC compiles rather fast.

I just use a post commit hook, feed the event through a simple fpc ratelimiter program (e.g. less than one build /5 minutes), and then just start a build+testsuite run.  The resuls of this is converted to a few simple static webpages.

If multiple commits come in quickly, one build is started, and the rest is defered 5-10 mins. 
This means 10 commits in rapid succession will only lead to two builds.

Comment: **a post commit hook** is some plugin for jenkins? or just hook on svn? how to do this? thanks.

Comment: I think he meant `git` version control system.

Comment: Actually FPC uses SVN, so both its Jenkins CI integrates with that, but yes, a hook from a version control system.  There is also a homegrown regression test system that runs nightly. I'm not too impressed with Jenkins over WAN links. A little issue with a checkout and you get a false positive build failure.